# Get List from a String Python

Tags: python, string, list

For example, I have a string `'[1,2,3]'`.

How can I make her turn a list `[1,2,3]`? quotes string. And if you have other characters remain string. How can I do this?

Examples:

```
input                 output

'[1,2,3]'            [1,2,3]

input                 output

"['1','2,'3']"     ['1','2','3']
```

Comment: You mean you have JSON data? Or is that Python data? Can you show us what you mean by 'other characters' here?

Comment: Yes, input and expected output would greatly help the question.

Comment: ok. edited with input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have Python literals in a string. Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse these as Python would.

Demo:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> literal_eval("['1','2','3']")
['1', '2', '3']
```

`ast.literal_eval()` can handle `None`, booleans, numbers, strings, unicode strings, tuple, list, dictionary and set literals, arbitrarily nested.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '[1,2,3]'
>>> l = s[1:-1].split(',')
>>> l
['1', '2', '3']
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: >>> print l
["'1'", "'2'", "'3'"] So you need to replace the " in each element of the list. with a null character.

Comment: This never results in *integer* values in the list.

Comment: `l = [int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(",")]` . But your solution is better.